# powershell - error converting webrequest results into XML

Tags: xml, powershell, unicode, byte-order-mark

I want to process XML file something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:Documents xmlns:tc="http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/Ticket" xmlns:oref="http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/ClientRef" xmlns:ns="http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/WB_DOC_SINGLE_01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.0">
  <ns:Owner>
    <ns:FSRAR_ID>3463047</ns:FSRAR_ID>
  </ns:Owner>
  <ns:Document>
    <ns:Ticket>
      <tc:TicketDate>2018-02-08T17:29:09.3041792</tc:TicketDate>
      <tc:Identity />
      <tc:DocId>2E47720A-58BC-4AF0-9159-5AD6A40C9792</tc:DocId>
      <tc:TransportId>38d9de5a-dd41-44ca-9ef3-0e404fef4bce</tc:TransportId>
      <tc:RegID>A13322D0-CB7F-455B-A7C6-C0CDC2AA4471</tc:RegID>
      <tc:DocHash />
      <tc:DocType>AsiiuTimesign</tc:DocType>
      <tc:Result>
        <tc:Conclusion>Accepted</tc:Conclusion>
        <tc:ConclusionDate>2018-02-08T17:29:09.3041792</tc:ConclusionDate>
        <tc:Comments>Документ успешно принят системой на обработку.</tc:Comments>
      </tc:Result>
    </ns:Ticket>
  </ns:Document>
</ns:Documents>
```

Which I get as a result of Invoke-WebRequest:

```
$url = "http://server/queue"
$webpage = ([xml]((Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec 60 $url).Content))
```

What I get is an error:

```
Cannot convert value "<xml body goes here>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because 
the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:5 char:1
+ $webpage = ([xml]((Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec 60 $url).Content))
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
```

Can anyone suggest why can't I transform the results of Invoke-WebRequest to XML type and how to deal with it?

EDIT

Ok, I tried saving request contents to the file and viewing it in HEX editor, now I see that file starts with `ff fe ff fe`. I also performed another request to another URL which result's content was casting ok to XML and it turns out it had only `ff fe` at the start. I deleted first `ff fe` from the file, read it in the script and it casted to XML successfully.

Now I see that response's content has BOM by itself but when I run ($response).Content I get a string with two BOMs. Why and how can I get correct string with just one BOM?

Comment: And if you remove the `[xml]`...it seems that the response is not a valid xml.

Comment: @Hackerman, why is it not valid?

Comment: Can you remove the `[xml]` from your request and add the response content to your question?

Comment: Just to be clear - it isn't really saying `<xml body goes here>` in the exception, is it? Because, if it is, it's clear where your problem comes from.

Comment: @Hackerman, basically xml that I get from "(Invoke-WebRequest).Content" is at start of the question. It just seems that I can't cast it to XML.

Comment: @Clijsters, no, there's body of actual xml in the exception

Comment: @ViktorOzerov Is there any chance on posting it? Just to be clear it isn't invalid...

Comment: `Cannot convert value "<xml body goes here>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because 
the specified node is the wrong type."`

Comment: @Hackerman Was this comment posted by mistake?

Comment: @Clijsters, added actual XML

Comment: _Why and how can I get correct string with just one BOM?_ Is it your server? You might want to fix its encoding, but this is not related tou your current question